# Python Removing [' '] from start and end of string when reading text from a file

Tags: python

I am reading some text from a text file that says hello my name is Matthew.
But when i print it it says ['Hello my name is matthew'].
Does anyone know how to trim the [' '] from the string?

Code below

```
File1 = open('Text.txt')
PlainText = File1.readlines()
File1.close()
print(PlainText)
```

Comment: `PlainText = File1.read().rstrip()`

Comment: When you print an object, python needs to decide what it should look like to humans. `['Hello my name is matthew']` is python's way of telling you that you have a list with a single string value. Your sring is at `PlainText[0]`.

Comment: You should use the method recommend by OneCricketeer.  But the wrong way to do it would be simply `print(PlainText[0])`.  Because the item is a list, so pulling out the first index in the list will get you your string.

Comment: There are different ways to read the file depending on what you want to do with it next. If your file only has a single line, then the `read` or `readline` methods are fine. If you want ot read multiple lines and have each line be a different string, then `readlines  or `for line in File1:` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s because `readlines` returns a list.

If your file contained multiple lines you would have many elements in the list. But as you only have one line it is the only element in the list.

Check the [IO documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for other methods to read single lines.